# simulation nodes python bake post

Tags: python, simulation-nodes

i am trying to bake a simulation in simulation nodes using python.

```
bpy.ops.object.simulation_nodes_cache_bake(selected=True)
print("bake complete")
```

things need to happen after the bake is complete (saving alembic, changing a few values, baking again, saving alembic again)

unfortunately, the bake simulation nodes operator outputs the bake complete print a second after the function is executed, even though the simulation hasn't finished baking yet.

anyone have any ideas how to fix that?